# Versioning numerical model input files

Tags: git, svn, version-control, numerical-methods

I'm sort of fishing for some ideas here. I work with a variety of open source numerical models and one thing that would be a huge help to those working with them would be to have the model input files kept in a versioned system. As you can imagine, tracking things using "v24a v24b v25a etc" isn't descriptive and necessarily intitive. I've decided to start brainstorming on the idea of creating a versioning system for these model files, specifically the finite element meshes which can be on the order of 500mb. So far as I can tell, this isn't something that's really been messed with before (potentially for good reason). The model data that is to be versioned is fairly simple and looks like the below:

**Section 1 (node locations)**

```
NID1 X1 Y1 Z1
NID2 X2 Y2 Z2
NID3 X3 Y3 Z3
etc
```

**Section 2 (element connectivity)**

```
EID1 NID1 NID2 NID3
EID2 NID5 NID6 NID1
etc
```

The problem with this data being used with versioning software is that the sequential Node ID's (NID in above) are very fluid. When nodes are added or deleted, large portions of the node table are re-written and thus, much of the file is changed leading to large deltas between versions and nearly full re-writes. This, of course, cascades to the elemental connectivity section as well.

My idea is to use hashes (md5, sha1, doesn't actually matter) to define nodal position IDs instead of just an arbitrary number. The hash would be based upon the X,Y position of the node and therefore would be static. These hashes can also then be referenced in the element connectivity section of the format as well. From here is where things get a little hazy for me. I have two ways to approach this, though I don't think they're optimal:

**Approach 1**
Write a single file with the node and element sections using alphabetically sorted hashes. This means that little of the file will change and it will generally create smaller deltas. This could potentially work with Subversion but likely not Git since Git keeps all versions of each file, and so then Git wouldn't have much performance/storage advantage over just using the original format.

**Approach 2**
Write a directory tree of files.

```
Model Directory
  |
  `--nodes
  |   `-node file 1
  |   `-node file 2
  |
  `--elements
      `element file 1
      `element file 2
```

For this then, the node file and element file would be files that contain minute bits of information. Just the X,Y,Z and hash for the nodes or the hash and connectivity for the elements. This seems (to me and I might be wrong) that it could work in theory with Git since the large majority of the files won't change for most commits. However, the issue is that the large number of files will be extremely slow and could overload the disk at some point since we're talking about close to 50 million files.

I'm wondering if anyone has any clever ideas to work around this type of problem so that I could generate some software that could act as a go-between for the modeling software and the versioning software. Or am I pretty much screwed. Neither of the approaches I've been able to come up with so far are the correct solution, in my mind at least, though I'm hoping I'm at least onto something.

Comment: You could try keeping a master file of seen points/nodes and regenerating id's based on that, but are you sure duplicate points are identical?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will think a while on how that could work. I do know that any node with the same position is identical since the information about the characteristics is stored elsewhere.